# jquery ajax store canvas in folder/on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, canvas, export

I have a question regarding this code snippet:

```
function upload(){
<!-- grab our drawing data from our myCanvas --> 
var myDrawing = document.getElementById("requiem");
<!-- start our datastring --> 
var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("image/png");
var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;   
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
<!-- specify our php processing page --> 
ajax.open("POST",'saveImage.php',true);
<!-- set the mime type so the image goes through as base64 --> 
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
     <!-- once the image data has been sent call a simple alert --> 
         if (ajax.readyState == 4){
             alert("image saved");
         }
}
    ajax.send(postData);
}
```

When I call the function `upload()` within jquery nothing happens.
I get the popup message indicating that the picture was successfully stored but it is not.

I was wondering if maybe the code needs to be rewritten to fit updated libraries?
I think it is quite old?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the content of saveImage.php ?